# How to make animation easing (ease-in and ease-out) duration-independent?

Tags: jquery, animation, easing

I'm using jQuery with [Easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) and i would like to achieve constant easing times for for animations of any duration:

```
Short animation (X milliseconds)
|<<<<|-------------------|>>>>|
 10ms                     10ms

Long animation (2X milliseconds)
|<<<<|-----------------------------------------|>>>>|
 10ms                                           10ms
```

Where `<<<<` / `>>>>` are easing-in / easing-out periods, and `---` denotes constant velocity movement.

Is there an easing function/plugin for that or should i give a time-dependent custom function for each animation like this and, if yes, then what kind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the callback function in the `.animate()` calls to chain animations:

```
var $obj     = $('#some-id'),
    ani_dist = 500;

//animate first easing
$obj.stop().animate({ left : 100 }, 500, 'easeOutCirc', function () {

    //animate main body of the animation
    $obj.animate({ left : (ani_dist - 100) }, 1000, 'linear', function () {

        //animate the last easing
        $obj.animate({ left : ani_dist }, 500, 'easeInCirc');
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what you want to set the animation to animate or what duration to use but there's an idea.

Comment: That is a solution i thought about, too, but the problem is that for longer and smoother animations it's difficult to fit an easing function on both ends — there's always a bit of a wobble on the "connection points". Is there an easing-in function graph that ends in a 45 degree line, while starts horizontally?

Comment: @ErnestsKarlsons Here are some graphs of the different easing types: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html

Comment: Stupid, just needed to look them up. For some reason i was sure that there is nothing suitable. Sorry and thanks for a fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the animate queen

```
//animate first easing
$obj.stop()
    .animate({ left : 100 }, 500, 'easeOutCirc')
    .animate({ left : (ani_dist - 100) }, 1000, 'linear')
    .animate({ left : ani_dist }, 500, 'easeInCirc')
;
```

See [jQuery.animate example-2](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#example-2)